# Oauth for Phonegapfo installed app

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0, google-plus, installed-applications

As I am new to Oauth 2.0,I want to implement oauth concept for our app,how can I implement that  for phone gap Installed application, I am going on trying  but i am unable to proceed forward tell me how to implement that/provide me some useful links with are working properly ....

Comment: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html

Comment: Thank you,but i followed your code process.I am getting Sign in button not diverting to login window giving the following error. "invalid parameter value for the origin: missing authority:file:// please help me.

Comment: In your code, what is your redirect_uri set as? Also, what type of installed application did you select?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use PhoneGap. Try checking out the Using [OAuth 2.0 with Google API in PhoneGap / Childbrowser](http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery).

The quick overview of how it should work is: You'll set up your client ID in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) as an "installed application". This plugin will enable the OAuth flow where you trigger the flow, the browser opens and the user sees and accepts a authorization dialog, the browser redirects to a success window that contains the authorization code in the title and body of the success page, which the Childbrowser reads from the title, passes back to your app, and then closes the success window. Your app then exchanges the authorization code for the access tokens that it needs.

Comment: Thank you,but i followed your code process.I am getting Sign in button not diverting to login window giving the following error. "invalid parameter value for the origin: missing authority:file:// please help me.